# Is a return ticket required to obtain a visa on arrival in Vientiane, Laos?

Tags: eu-citizens, visas-on-arrival, laos, vientiane, return-tickets

Let's assume an EU citizen who is entering by air to Laos with a valid passport. Is he required to have a return ticket already booked to obtain the visa on arrival when arriving to VTE (Vientiane) airport?

From the information I find online, none mentions that but since I cannot find any information directly from Laos authorities, I would like to double check it. The reason is that in many countries the visa on arrival is only granted if a return ticket is available. In some even you cannot check in if you do not hold the return ticket.

Comment: I added the EU citizen tag, but it might vary by actual country of citizenship.

Comment: Thank you. In the list of countries that have different conditions indeed I never saw any distinction of EU countries.

Comment: Did you ever find confirmation that proof on onward travel was not required? Other than anecdotal info that it is not, the best I could locate was that on a tour operator site that said *you may not berequired to show a return ticket if you are travelling overland. However, it is wise to procure an itinerary from a travel agent to avoid problems.* Of course, that may just be self promotion.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of similar questions online for Laos, but [The WorldTravelGuide](https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/asia/laos/passport-visa/)
tries to index information about this topic, and according to them - if flying in, **citizens of Britain or other EU countries require a return ticket.**

From [sources online](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/ShowTopic-g293949-i9320-k11439787-Getting_Through_Customs_with_no_onward_travel_ticket-Laos.html) it appears that if you get asked, you could say you're continuing on by land travel, but may be asked for evidence of this, and all you'd need is for some pedantic gate agent to cause you problems.

Answer (score 2):

I was stopped at check-in by Silk Air before leaving Singapore pre pandemic. Was going to come back by train but they said no.